# Set value in map golang, type error, unsure how to fix

Tags: go

I'm trying to set a key:value pair in golang as a local cache.

When I set a new pair, i receive an error because of the struct of the entry value.

```
type Cache struct {
    cache map[string]*entry
}

type entry struct {
    value string
    err   error
}

func NewCache() *Cache {
    return &Cache{cache: make(map[string]*entry)}
}

func (c *Cache) Set(key string, value *entry) (string, string) {
    c.cache[key] = value

    return key, value

}
```

I can see that the value pair requires both an error and value type output, yet I am confused about how to Set the value while using that error value if that makes sense?

#### Update including get function,

```
func (c *Cache) Get(key string) (string, error) {
    res, ok := c.cache[key]
    if !ok {
        res = &entry{}
        // res.value, res.err = f()
        c.cache[key] = res
    }
    return res.value, res.err
```

What am i missing - any pointer appreciated.

My intention is to be able to pass the value string from entry into the map, essentially.

I have begun just re-writing a more minimal version, but this format i think makes sense if i can get the Set functionality to work :S

Comment: Did you intend to pass an `*entry` to the `Set` function?

Comment: Let me expand the code, the error is moreso for the Get function, i will include it.

Comment: changed it, typo there

Comment: There's a compilation error on the return from Cache.Set. It's unclear what the intent of the return value is, so it's difficult to suggest a fix.  The code compiles otherwise.

Comment: The intention is to create a local cache, so the Set should return if it has worked or not I suppose?

Comment: How can Set fail?

Comment: @LeCoda you suppose? You don't seem to really have a question here. If you do, please let us know, we would love to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Set` method on the `Cache` has declared return values of `(string, string)`, but you return `key, value`, the first of which is a string, but the second is of type `*entry`, not `string`. To fix this, either return a `string` as the second return value or change the second declared return type to `*entry`.

Given the variable name `value` (type `*entry`) and the `value` (type `string`) field on the `entry` type, it's unclear what the desired behavior is here. However, since `entry` is a private type, I'm guessing that you don't actually want to have to pass a value of type `*entry` to the public `Set` method.

Perhaps this is what you're after:

```golang
func (c *Cache) Set(key string, value string, err error) (string, string) {
    c.cache[key] = &entry{value, err}
    return key, value
}
```

But also maybe you meant:

```golang
func (c *Cache) Set(key string, ent *entry) (string, *entry) {
    c.cache[key] = ent
    return key, ent
}
```

Though in either case the return values seem unnecessary as they're the same as the given values. You might consider making `Set` a void method instead.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to implement this now, coming up against some type errors still, will test and ask more questions if that's okay

Comment: @LeCoda yeah, let me know how it goes